# What is the performance impact of using Casbah as opposed to directly using MongoDb java driver?

Tags: mongodb, casbah

Casbah is another layer on top of [Java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) for MongoDb. Would this reduce performance of queries and updates in MongoDb database in scala projects when using Casbah as opposed to directly using the Java driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(I'm the author and maintainer of Casbah)*

It should be negligible - I have worked hard over the last 2 years to keep the thickness of any wrapping to the bare minimum.

I'd venture to guess that most users will never begin to experience *ANY* kind of noticable pain or slowdown as a result of Casbah's wrapper code over using the straight Java driver.

In many cases because of optimisations Scala is able to make at compile time, I have also observed places where Casbah performs flat out better (especially for iteration type operations) than the Java driver alone.